# Using Blender Game Engine for VR 360 tour on Mobile, is it doable?

Tags: game-engine, export

I'm sorry if my question sounds clumsy, I'm not a seasoned BGE user.

I'd like to make a virtual tour for Gear VR and/or Google Cardboard in the BGE that works on Mobile.

Is this doable in a user friendly way using the BGE? Can I export to Mobile (android, IOS, Windows Phone)? I know this is possible using Unity, but I find Unity difficult to use. I've tried UE4, but the process is a big mess, it requires a buggy multi-level hack that only results in wasting my time.

Comment: chances are good you could do this in the BGE. Exporting it to work on mobile devices would be much, much harder.

Comment: So BGE cannot export an executive file in general? Or only for mobile devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blender Game Engine only runs on Windows Mac and Linux, not on mobile platforms like iOS or Android. And even then, in desktop OSs it is [often regarded as an aging and limited game engine](https://code.blender.org/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/), needing a long overdue overhaul, when compared to more modern solutions out there.

It will in fact be retired as of [version 2.80 going forward](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/what-will-happen-with-blender-2-8-game-engine/106988#106988), and it is will not receive further official development.

There was an [experimental BGE APK version](https://download.blender.org/demo/android/) running on Android but it is just a proof of concept, very feature limited and not actively maintained. Also it certainly predates the emergence of modern VR so I wouldn't expect it to support anything of the kind at all.

You could probably use Blender in your pipeline for asset and environment production but I wouldn't rely on it as a lasting game engine solution, and certainly never for mobile platforms.

You could alternatively use any of the well know solutions out there like Unity or Unreal, or perhaps look into WebGL for a more universal browser based solution.

There is also the [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com/en/) plugin for Blender which now supports browser based Virtual Reality through the [WebVR API](https://webvr.info/), even on mobile platforms. It has a full GUI inside Blender for most basic functionality from creation of assets, materials, animations, to basic interaction logic.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, I will definitely research Blend4Web