# How do I export a blender game to be played within my website?

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, export

Basically what the title says.

I haven't made the website yet, so I'm not looking for a specific solution. Is there ANY way that it is GENERALLY possible to play a blender game in-browser?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/using-blender-game-engine-for-vr-360-tour-on-mobile-is-it-doable

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.  As described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/using-blender-game-engine-for-vr-360-tour-on-mobile-is-it-doable) you can create only Windows, Mac and Linux native applications from BGE.

If you want to create a 3D web application from blender, you should
use a specific addons:

- [Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/)
- [Verdge3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/)

Both looks the same, but main difference between them is that Blend4Web uses JavaScript as main scripting tool, Verdge3D uses special block-style logic editor