# Pull Apart Educational Model

Tags: game-engine

Is it still possible to make a model that I can export to somewhere and when viewed the user can interact by clicking on certain items for them to be hidden? I'd have thought the game engineer would have done that but I know that's been removed, it'd be nice if I didn't need to ship it to unity first. 
cheers

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/using-blender-game-engine-for-vr-360-tour-on-mobile-is-it-doable

Answer (score 1):

So here is how you would do this using game logic. (The blend file at the end if you want to skip my explanation).

1) Connect an *Always* sensor to a *Mouse* actuator (the default state of this actuator is to make the mouse visible so you shouldn't have to change anything).

2) Where the yellow box is add a *Boolean* property and make sure it's starting state is *True* (checked).

3) Add two mouse sensors (as seen in the light blue box). Set one to *Mouse Over* and the other to *Left Button*. Connect both sensors to **the same** controller and make sure it is set to *Add* (that is the default). Now connect the *Add* controller to a *Property* actuator set to toggle the property you created in step 2 (see the dark blue box).

4) Add a *Property* sensor and set it to *Equal* "True" then connect it to a *Visibility* actuator in which *Visible* is checked.

5) Add a *Property* sensor and set it to *Equal* "False" then connect it to a *Visibility* actuator in which *Visible* is unchecked and *Occlusion* is checked.

[image]

[image]